# how to show fetched data from database in a form (not in table) ?

Tags: php

I want to echo data from database in a form where I can edit it and update it in database.
my script is showing values in a table. At bottom I need an edit link, where I can see values in form and then edit and make updation in database.

```
 include 'config.php';
$list="select * from donated where d_id=".$_GET['user_id']."";
 $data=mysqli_query($con,$list); 
 $info = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

 echo "<table border='1'>";
 echo "<tr><td>" ."<strong>NAME OF DONER</strong>" . "</td><td>" .  $info['d_name']  . "</td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><td>"."<strong>AMOUNT DONATED</strong>"."</td><td>" . $info['d_amount'] . "</td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><td>"."<strong>CONTACT</strong>"."</td><td>" . $info['d_phone'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>"; 

echo "<a herf='#'>click here to edit it.</a></br>";
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.fcom/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: whats wrong in my script ??

Comment: You are using $_GET straight into your query.  You should use placeholders instead. Have a look here http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just render you form input elements as per usual; only default the value attribute to the required variable.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="doner_name" value="<?php echo $info['d_name']; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border='1'>
<tr>
        <td><strong>NAME OF DONER</strong></td>
        <td><?php echo  $info['d_name'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><strong>AMOUNT DONATED</strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['d_amount'];?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
        <td><strong>CONTACT</strong></td>
        <td><?php echo  $info['d_phone'];?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
        <td><strong>NAME OF DONER</strong></td>
        <td><?php echo  $info['d_name'];?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<a herf='#'>click here to edit it.</a></br>
```